# Coloring edges of a polygon differently

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, polygon

I would like to draw a regular 21 polygon, where the edges are labelled and have arrows in the middle using different colors. This is what I have done so far
[image]
using this code

```
    \documentclass[margin=0pt]{standalone}
%---------------------------- Tikz Libraries ------------------------------%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
         decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
            postaction={decorate}, }, 
        ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [
  draw,
  minimum size=0.9\textwidth,
  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=21,
  rotate=270,
  ]{};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
  \path[red,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
   \path[red,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
  \path[blue,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/13/3} %inverse \beta's
   \path[blue,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {13/14/1, 16/17/2,19/20/3} %\xi's
  \path[teal,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[teal,midway]{$\xi_ {\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {15/16/1,18/19/2,21/1/3} %inverse \xi's
   \path[teal,auto=right,-<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[teal,midway]{$\xi_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {14/15/1,17/18/2,20/21/3} %\rho's
  \path[violet,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[violet,midway]{$\rho_{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would also like to color the edges of the polygon corresponding to the labels. But I am just able to color all edges in the same color. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

for above image i made the following changes in mwe which you provide in question:

- delete option `draw` in polygon style definition
- all `\path` in loops replace with `\draw`